# How do I enable callback functions using ipython console in either jupyter or spyder?

Tags: python, user-interface

I am relatively new to python and I am trying to make my first GUI. I have a callback function that I am trying to execute that changes the background color of the GUI window depending on what Radiobutton is pressed. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Python GUI")
colors = ["Blue", "Gold", "Red"]

def radCall():
    radSel=radVar.get()
    if   radSel == 0: win.configure(background=colors[0])
    elif radSel == 1: win.configure(background=colors[1])
    elif radSel == 2: win.configure(background=colors[2])

radVar = tk.IntVar()

radVar.set(99)

for col in range(3):
    curRad = 'rad' + str(col)
    curRad = tk.Radiobutton(win, text=colors[col], variable=radVar, value=col, command=radCall)
    curRad.grid(column=col, row=6, sticky=tk.W)

win.mainloop()
```

When I execute the script after writing it in a text editor, it works perfectly but when I try to execute the same code (minus win.mainloop) in an interactive environment such as spyder or jupyter notebook, the radiobuttons appear but they do not execute the background color change. I suspect this has something to do with the fact that it involves a callback function but I am not positive. How should I edit my code to make it work in an interactive shell or better set up my interactive environment for using callback functions?

Answer (score 0):

Tried running you code in Spyder and first have to say:

1. To start the program you have to use mainloop()
2. I ran the code with/without the win.mainloop and noticed that without the win.mainloop, the code runs but not GUI is created because of point 1. With the win.mainloop(), noticed the window was small so I had to expand it to see the changes, otherwise though it was not working. Suggestion is increase the window size or set the minimum size e.g. `win.minsize(width=XXX,height=XXX)`
3. Better to use:

   if **name** == '**main**':
   win.mainloop()

Unless you give more explanation, you can not run the program without the .mainloop()

Comment: Thanks for your response. I forgot to mention that I add %gui tk when running the code so the GUI changes dynamically as I code. The reason I think it may have to do with callback is that I think the problem comes with the radVar.get() part of the code. Can't seem to resolve this so it retrieves it with the callback function.

Comment: What about defining `radVar = tk.IntVar()` at the top when also defining the `win=tk.TK()`?

Comment: Tried that too and no luck. Thanks for the suggestion tho